# Nesting a tag, hover state ignored

Tags: css, hover, nested, underline

```
<a href="#" class="a-hover-underline">
    <div class="grid-md-2-3 background-div"></div>

    <div class="grid-1 grid-md-1-3 content-div">
        <h2>some text...</h2>
        <p>some text...</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

So I have this setup with a nested 'a' tag... What I want to achieve is to underline the text on anchor hover. I have a:hover { text-decoration: underline } in my stylesheet file, but the text doesn't get underlined on anchor hover. I tried testing hover event on that 'a' tag with jQuery and it works.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: works here : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/r01sq43e/

Comment: I think there's some problem in your CSS.  can you post a minimal complete examples without solving it yourself ?

Comment: I solved the problem. I had to add additional * inside my 'a' style. Sass code looks something like this:

a {
    &, * { text-decoration: none; }

    &:hover {
        &, *: text-decoration: underline;
    }
}

I guess there's a problem with styling nested elements inside 'a' tag (although by html5 spec 'a' tag can be nested!), looks like styles applied to 'a' get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the original without hover to not underline and it should work.

```
.a-hover-underline:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
.a-hover-underline { text-decoration:none; }
```

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/d2k2t7oc/

Answer (score 0):

[see this](http://jsfiddle.net/w4fnn0La/) 
this is working for me. I am getting yout question wrong?

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```